# How to redirect tty1 to an X11 (KDE) Konsole shell?

Tags: terminal, kde, x11, tty, konsole

I would like to see what is going on at `tty1` - the console I was booting from - 
while I am now on `tty7` running X11 with KDE4, without switching back to `tty1` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>).

I would like to see it inside KDE's Konsole, if possible. I would like to have `tty1` redirected into Konsole, including all boot history that was scrolling down while I was booting.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fold -bw80 /dev/vcs1`

Substitute 80 for your actual width. This doesn't support attributes, the `/dev/vcsa*` include attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Check out ttysnoop: http://www.linuxhelp.net/guides/ttysnoop/

I think you will not be able to see everything since boot, only everything after you connected to the snoop session.